# Why are we ignoring the effect of rotation of earth while equating initial and final energy in this question?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, energy-conservation, work

> A satellite of mass $m$ is launched vertically upwards with an initial speed $u$ from the surface of the earth. After it reaches height $R$($R$= radius of the earth), it ejects a rocket of mass $\frac{m}{10}$ so that subsequently the satellite moves in a circular orbit. The kinetic energy of the rocket is ($G$ is the gravitational constant; $M$ is the mass of the earth)

My solution to the question:

Applying energy conservation,

$K_i + U_i = K_f + U_f$

$\frac{1}{2}mu^2+(-\frac{GMm}{R})=\frac{1}{2}mv^2-\frac{GMm}{2R}$

$V =\sqrt{u^2-\frac{GM}{R}}$....(i)

[image]

By momentum conservation, we have

$\frac{m}{10}v_T=\frac{9m}{10}\sqrt{\frac{GM}{R}}$ ...(ii)

&$\frac{m}{10}v_r=mv$

$\implies\frac{m}{10}v_r=m\sqrt{u^2-\frac{GM}{R}}$ ...(iii)

Kinetic energy of rocket

$=\frac{1}{2}m({v_T}^2+{v_R}^2)$
Putting values and simpllyfying,

$=\frac{m}{20}(100u^2-\frac{119GM}{2R})$

I could work out the solution but I am still a little confused about the very first step. Why are we ignoring the effect of rotation of earth while writing energy conservation?

Comment: Rotation of earth does not do any work , so it does not produce any energy

Comment: @NaveenV Please don’t use comments to answer the question. To post a brief answer, use the answer box.

Comment: ah gotcha , I felt like this was not suitable enough/long enough for an answer to be posted in the answer box  @rob

Comment: @NaveenV True but I am getting confused because the satellite would also have that  velocity  when launched from the surface and it might do some work idk

Comment: @Satya , its doing some work yes , but that work is not due to the rotation of earth , it exerts the force for the work against gravity , it is solely based on the satellite's ability and not the influence of rotation of earth

Comment: The question gives no information about the latitude of the launch site;  therefore any consideration of the effect of the earth's rotation is impossible.  What if it's launched from the North Pole?

Comment: @DJohnM  I do not mean his _specific_ calculation, but calculations where launches are near the equator.

Comment: You can include the earth's rotation in certain calculations, but where rotation effects are relevant i.e., at or near the equator, where the tangential speed is significant. This is why nearly all launches occur there.

Comment: This has the potential to be a good question, but you must edit it to focus on the *concepts* that you want help with (presumably rotation / angular momentum).